# Query all the users in a specific BIM 360 account

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

how can I get Query all the users in a specific BIM 360 account? with no limit, because I have over 100 users :
[image]

Comment: You can use the `offset` url parameter to retrieve individual pages of the complete list of users. See how this Node.js library is requesting the users in a while loop until the page is empty: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-server-utils/blob/5a00ea4e67bf26ba1cf1b2113f1e3d83849d4e40/src/bim360.ts#L852-L856.

Comment: great thanks Petr :)

Answer (score 0):

max limit means the limit of one page (the call of one time).e.g.  if you set 50, then every call, 50 items only. By default offset = 0. It means starting with the first item. i.e. one call with limit=50&offset=0 will give you  No. 0-49 items only.
one call with limit=50&offset=120 will give you  No. 120-169 items only.

The response of the call will tell pagination info. e.g. when I set limit=2&offset=0. It tells total number of users is 10. The next page (nexturl) will be from No 2,3.

```
"pagination": {
    "limit": 2,
    "offset": 0,
    "totalResults": 10,
    "nextUrl": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/xxxxxx- 
5d39-43cb-b4c4-xxxxxx/users?limit=2&sort=name&offset=2"
},
```

If calling nexturl, it will tell the url of previous page(No 2,3 only) and next page (No 4,5 only).

```
"pagination": {
    "limit": 2,
    "offset": 2,
    "totalResults": 10,
    "nextUrl": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/xxxxxx- 
  5d39-43cb-b4c4-xxxxxx/users?limit=2&offset=4&sort=name",
    "previousUrl": 
  "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/xxxxxx-5d39-43cb-b4c4- 
xxxxxx/users?limit=2&offset=0&sort=name"
},
```

And my colleague Petr's sample will be also a good reference for coding.